# How to redirect http requests to a service running in other port

Tags: nginx, networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a certain machine that recently got external access, but only to a few ports (SSH, HTTP and HTTPS.) Now this machine must provide access to some other services (e.g. RabbitMQ, Tomcat, etc), but I don't want to give these ports external access.

My first thought was to redirect HTTP requests on port 80 to those services. For example:

`http://<machine_ip>:80/tomcat` should be equivalent to `http://<machine_ip>:8080`

I was wondering if Nginx, HAProxy, or some other proxy-related software could help me out with this. What suggestions do you have? Keep in mind that I am fairly new to system administration in general.

Comment: Why do you only have "a few ports"?

Comment: This machine actually belongs to the institution I'm interning at. My boss thought it could be risky to give access to so many ports. If it is the only solution, I'll probably have to ask him to do it.

Comment: OK, the first thing to do is to figure out exactly what needs access to those services. Those are not normally services you would expose directly to the world.

Comment: There is an Android application that will need to access a Tomcat back-end server which will be running inside that machine, so a user wants access to that. I believe the app will also need to communicate with a RabbitMQ server. Honestly, think this machine should not have generalized external access, but the developers are not in the same network as the machine. How should I proceed?

Comment: I would be having a chat with the developers.

Comment: What your asking for in your original question is exactly what a reverse proxy, like Nginx, is meant for.  Go to http://nginx.org/en/docs/ and you'll find examples of how you can service your app's requests.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you: You can use Apache for proxying (clustering) the webpage. For example, you enter http://example.com/tomcat and Apache will pass the request to http://example.com:8080/. It is easy to do:

When you defined a new VirtualHost block in the Apache configuration file, then add these lines to it (make sure you have mod_proxy enabled):

```
<Proxy balancer://custom-balancer-name>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 #Enter the address of the second machine or service
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /tomcat balancer://custom-balancer-name
ProxyReversePass /tomcat balancer://custom-balancer-name
```

Hope you find my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use HAProxy for that. Please take your time because it's not a easy task especially when the topic is new.
There are several options which you can use.

- add per service one listen block

  ```
  listen rabbit
    bind ::5672
    mode tcp
    ... some other haproxy options
    server rabbit-srv IP:PORT

  listen ....
  ```
- you can use SNI ([Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#page-6)) routing with frontend/backend combination to keep a single port usage for the services which use TLS for there communication.
  I have created a picture how the SNI Routing works, the example configuration uses HAProxy [How does the SNI Routing works in HAProxy](https://www.me2digital.com/blog/2019/05/haproxy-sni-routing/)

I don't know which version of HAProxy you use therefore here the link for the latest HAProxy version 2.2.
http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file for doing that. First, create a `.htaccess` file in your document root, and then paste these lines into it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^tomcat/(.*[^/])/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I hope I helped you.